# Updating object variable in a different Activity

Tags: android, object

I have a custom class for creating objects, something like this (pseudocode):

```
class PhotoObject implements Parcelable {
    String photoUrl;
    String uploaderName;
    int numberOfLikes;
    // constructor, getters, setters, parcelable methods...
}
```

I have an `ArrayList`of `PhotoObject`objects in `MainActivity`. Each of them represents a photo in a `GridView` in `MainActivity`. When I click on a photo, I pass that particular `PhotoObject` to the `PhotoDetails` activity. If I like a photo in `PhotoDetails`, `numberOfLikes` variable count increases by one (`numberOfLikes++`).
HERE'S THE PROBLEM:
 When I return to the `MainActivity` the `numberOfLikes` variable (of course) is not increased by one, it's the same as it was before I liked a photo.

So my question is **what is the best way to change this variable** in an object that's in the `MainActivity` (inside the `ArrayList` of `PhotoObject` objects)? I thought about making `numberOfLikes` variable `static`, but that would mean that it's the same for all object instances, right?

I hope I explained my problem clear enough :)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried making number of likes static and then calling

```
YOUR_CLASS_NAME.numberOfLikes++;
```

Comment: I'll try, but doesn't that mean that all PhotoObject objects will have the same number of likes?

Comment: Ok, I tried it and it doesn't work, because "static" means that all objects share the same variable, thus the same number of likes. In my example every photo has different number of likes. One solution would be that I'd pass the new number of likes through intent back to MainActivity and update the existing object in ArrayList. But I'm wondering if there's any better solution?

Comment: oh I am sorry I thougth it was the all in all likes

Comment: Have you ever done any similar app? How did you manage a problem like that? Am I doing it right to pass a selected object to a new Activity, or is it better to do it any other way? Any advice would be helpful :)

Comment: I used a whole class just to keppe my variables all using static

Comment: Alexander: A friend suggested me using startActivityForResult and I think it will serve my purpose. Thanks anyway :)